# Mysql: limits on table count, rows, and such

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a social network.

From what I've gathered, there's a limit at 1792 for number of tables in a mysql cluster. I will probably end up with 100-200 tables for now. Is this reasonable/acceptable? Or is my db schema horrible like this?  What is reasonable for a large scale project such as a social network?

Also, what then is the limit to number of rows per table? Some of my tables will be limited to a few dozen or a few hundred rows, but others (such as user messages and statistics) can get into the millions, billions. Is there a reasonable limit to how many rows I should place into each table? If it's better for me, I can create statistics tables by year (stats2010, stats2011).

I can read the internet all day, but most of the information out there only tells me what are min/maxes for database design, and not what is good db design. The earlier in my project's life I can solve these problems the better I will be in the long run.

Any other crucial pointers I should know about? I am still learning about max connections, upload timeouts, and dozens more, but I would like to start with this. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: The largest MySQL database I ever managed had 112 tables; the largest table had over one billion rows and several tables had over 100 million rows.  It performed moderately well, given that we were running on some low-end hardware.  It really depends on how you use the database, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...will probably end up with 100-200 tables for now. Is this reasonable/acceptable? Or is my db schema horrible like this? What is reasonable for a large scale project such as a social network?

It's hard to say without any details about what you are doing in the tables.  "social network" isn't enough to me for context, but I see it having tables for:

- Users(user_id, details, password)
- Friends (user_id, friend_id)

> what then is the limit to number of rows per table?

That [depends on the MySQL table engine - MyISAM has a 4 GB limit; InnoDB is different.  See this link for more details](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000796.html).

> If it's better for me, I can create statistics tables by year (stats2010, stats2011).

Sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: My tables run the gamut from simple 20 rows*3 columns to sort of complex news db with already 400 rows*8 columns. It may be premature optimization, but is it bad?

Comment: After coming across this page (http://www.mikebernat.com/blog/MySQL_-_InnoDB_vs_MyISAM) I determined I have been using InnoDB for all my tables so far.

Comment: @Bryan: InnoDB is my preference as well, but the table has to be MyISAM in order to use Full Text Search (FTS) :/  Your table description is still too high level to provide value for reflection.